# C++ Merge Sort returning original vector

Tags: c++, mergesort

I have been attempting to make a merge sort using vectors in C++ and am running into an issue where any vector input is sorted into its original order. I have based the algorithm off the geeks4geeks site here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

So far I have spent about five hours attempting to find the source of the error and it seems that upon ending the merge function the vector somehow goes back to its original format, but I am unsure why. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void merge(vector<int> vect, int p, int q, int r) {

    int i, j, k, n1, n2;

    n1 = q - p + 1;
    n2 = r - q;

    vector<int> L, R;

    L.resize(n1);
    R.resize(n2);

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = vect[p + i];
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = vect[q + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = p;


    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            vect[k] = L[i];
            i++;

        }
        else {
            vect[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    while (i < n1) {
        vect[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        vect[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}



void mergeSort(vector<int> vect, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;

        mergeSort(vect, p, q);
        mergeSort(vect, q + 1, r);

        merge(vect, p, q, r);


    }
}

int main() {

    vector<int> vect{4,3,5,6,7,8};
    mergeSort(vect, 0, vect.size() - 1);


    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) { 
        cout << vect[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing your vectors by value, hence they're not changed outside of the function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing vectors to a function, value vs reference C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647152/passing-vectors-to-a-function-value-vs-reference-c)

Comment: you should pass the vector by reference  vector & myvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should know the difference between:

- **pass by value**
- **pass by reference**

  Go and check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value#373429).

---

Secondly, you should change your code as it is shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//using namespace std; forget about it, start using std::whatever_it_is_in_here


void merge(std::vector<int> &vect, int p, int q, int r) // note the & near vect
{
    int i, j, k, n1, n2;

    n1 = q - p + 1;
    n2 = r - q;

    std::vector<int> L, R;

    L.resize(n1);
    R.resize(n2);

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = vect[p + i];
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = vect[q + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = p;


    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            vect[k] = L[i];
            i++;

        }
        else {
            vect[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    while (i < n1) {
        vect[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        vect[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}



void mergeSort(std::vector<int> &vect, int p, int r) // note the & near vect
{
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;

        mergeSort(vect, p, q);
        mergeSort(vect, q + 1, r);

        merge(vect, p, q, r);


    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect{4,3,5,6,7,8};
    mergeSort(vect, 0, vect.size() - 1);


    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect[i] << "\n"; // note \n instead of std::endl

    return 0; // you forgot the return statement 
}
```

---

1. You forgot the **return statement** in the main function.
2. Stop using *using namespace std*. Check why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
3. Note the `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`. You can understand more of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Comment: You could also use the range-based for loop in the main function and instead of writing `for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) std::cout << vect[i] << "\n";` it becomes     `for (int i : vect)    std::cout << i << "\n";`. Yet this is possible since C++11.

Comment: Omitting `return 0` in `main()` is valid C++ and has defined behavior, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c. That said, it doesn't hurt to add it anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems my experience with Java has crippled me again! I'll certainly read the links you've provided.