# Sort vector of object receive stack overflow exception c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl, std

I'm trying to sort a vector of `Student` objects by an attribute:

```
class Student
{
    private:
        std::string nume;
        int an;
        std::list<Curs> cursuri;
        ...
    public:
        Student();
        Student(std::string nume, int an);
        virtual ~Student();
        ...
};
```

with these sorting method comparatator:

```cpp
bool Student::sortByMedie(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    return a.medie < b.medie;
}
```

```cpp
void sortStudenti(std::vector<Student> studenti) {

    std::sort(studenti.begin(), studenti.end(), Student::sortByMedie);

    for (auto student : studenti) {
        student.afisare();
    }
}
```

But I am encounter a problem with a stack overflow exception when the sort method is called:

> The thread 0x4f6c has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown at 0x776CBA3E (ntdll.dll) in LAB3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002FF0). Unhandled exception at 0x776CBA3E (ntdll.dll) in LAB3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002FF0).

I'm assuming the problem is somewhere in a reallocation of vector size in memory. If I browse through the stack trace beyond the memory allocation functions, the last function of my own code (i.e. not standard library) is a `Curs` copy constructor called by a swap between two `Cusr` elements, that is invoked by `Curs::operator=`

This is the creation of vector:

```cpp
    std::vector<Student> studenti;
    auto student1 = Student("gigel marian", 3);
    student1.addCursuri(generateCoursList());
    auto student2 = Student("gigel marian2", 3);
    student2.addCursuri(generateCoursList());
    auto student3 = Student("gigel marian3", 3);
    student3.addCursuri(generateCoursList());
    auto student4 = Student("gigel marian4", 3);
    student4.addCursuri(generateCoursList());
    auto student5 = Student("gigel marian5", 3);
    student5.addCursuri(generateCoursList());

    studenti.push_back(student1);
    studenti.push_back(student2);
    studenti.push_back(student3);
    studenti.push_back(student4);
    studenti.push_back(student5);
```

In first place I tried with this method:

```cpp
void sortStudenti(std::vector<Student> studenti) {
    struct studentCompare
    {
        bool operator()(Student const& a, Student const& b)
        {
            return a.getMedie() > b.getMedie();
        }
    };

    std::sort(studenti.begin(), studenti.end(), studentCompare());

    for (auto student : studenti) {
        student.afisare();
    }
}
```

but I got some `const` access errors, so I tried in another way.

**Edit: additional code**

The full code is available on [github](https://github.com/Gradin98/nokia_learn)

Comment: @Grandin98 you're also looping through the studenti vector by value and not by references, which means you're calling the afisare function on copied objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for

Comment: Why are you passing the vector by value and not by reference?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647152/passing-vectors-to-a-function-value-vs-reference-c

Comment: Regarding the stack overflow excpetion is probably related t your Student class and how it handles copying.

Comment: @EyalD I didn't pass the vector as a reference because I don't want to modify the original list

Comment: @Liuka probably you are right, because I receive this exception on "new" operator, I guess I need to overload that operator ?

Comment: could not reproduce stackoverflow exception. post the class definition itself

Comment: @Gradin98 it really depends on the implementation. Post the code of the class

Comment: @mangusta I upload the project on github:
https://github.com/Gradin98/nokia_learn

Comment: @Gradin98 your github code does not have `sortByMedie`. is it `sortByName`?

Comment: @mangusta yes, I uploaded the code and after I change that name, sorry for this

Comment: @Gradin98 I still could not reproduce the stackoverflow exception. post the error logs that you see

Comment: What do you mean by `"const access errors"`?  My guess would be that the `Student::getMedie()` member isn't `const` qualified but is being called against a `const` instance.

Comment: @mangusta, https://i.imgur.com/4cUF5FW.png the picture with the exception error

and the logs if would help

The thread 0x4f6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x776CBA3E (ntdll.dll) in LAB3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002FF0).
Unhandled exception at 0x776CBA3E (ntdll.dll) in LAB3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002FF0).

Comment: @G.M. yes, that's the problem if I use that method.

Comment: @Gradin98 You need to produce a [Minimal Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Linking to a Github project is not sufficient - SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: After having reproduced the problem, I have edited the question providing vital information on the stack trace which shows the origin of the issue.  May be it could be worth for future readers of this question to add in the "additional code" section the relevant part of the `Curs` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `sort()` tries to swap `Student` elements, it makes temporary copies of `Student` elements. Since you do not specify anything else, it's the default member-by-member copy that will be performed.

In your `Student` class, you have a list of `Curs`. The list is simlarly copied with the `Curs` elements it contains. But for Curs, you have defined your own assignement operator:

```
Curs& Curs::operator=(Curs arg) noexcept
{
    std::swap(*this, arg);
    return *this;
}
```

The code that is behind the `swap()` generated makes you copy Curs again,  which will call the swap and the Curs again, .... and so on until the stack overflows or the memory is out.

By the way, I see that you have created this operator to circumvent the limitations behind the const members that Curs class contains. Tricking the compiler in this way to change a const element is undefined behavior.  So get rid of constness for members that need to be copied.

Just get rid of this (wrongly implemented) operator and the constness, and it will work.

---

#### Additional recommendations

This problem is indeed a complex one to handle with just some extracts of code. Especially when the problem is not where we think it is.  So I can only recommend you in future:

**Exploit the error information you have to its best extent**

- Post your complete error message in your question.
- In the case of a stack overflow: browse through the stack trace until you find some code of yours, to see in which part of your code it occurs. This helps to narrow down the research.
- If you browse a little bit more, you can also check if there is an endless recursion  (the most frequent reason for a stack overflow with small data amount): a very long succession of almost identical calls is a typical symptom.

**Reduce the risk of errors**

- Before starting to build more complex classes, make tests to ensure that the underlying classes work as expected.
- Even if you have not enough time to write extensive tests, you should at least try every class member function.  If you would have done a test that just checks if the `Curs::operator=` works, you would have saved you a lot of additional experiments ;-)

Comment: well done, I couldn't even compile that code (minGW g++). I removed that operator overload function altogether in order to compile at least. couldn't even imagine that was the reason

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your vector by reference and without changing your objects by passing them to the loop by `const` reference, as follows.

But make sure that the member function `afisare` is const

```
void sortStudenti(std::vector<Student>& studenti) {
    struct studentCompare
    {
        bool operator()(Student const& a, Student const& b)
        {
            return a.getMedie() > b.getMedie();
        }
    };


    std::sort(studenti.begin(), studenti.end(), studentCompare());

    for (const auto& student : studenti) {
        student.afisare();
    }
}
```

But I think there is another reason for the exception. You should have checked your class definition

Comment: this answer is not related to the issue specified in the question header

Comment: @mangusta the asker wanted to pass the object by references without changing them to avoid copying!!. See the comments on the question.