# Why don't I have access to the private values of a class through a friend function?

Tags: c++, function, class

I create a class, and in the class I declare a `friend` function so that I can later change a private value with an `if..else` statement, though I can't even change it without the `if..else`.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A {
        
        private:

            float money;
            friend void _setMoney(A a, float i);

        public: 

        void setMoney(float i) {
            money = i;
        };

        float getMoney() {
            return money;
        };

        A(float i) {
            i = money;
        };

    };

    void _setMoney(A a, float i) {
        a.setMoney(i);
    };

    int main(){

        A a(0);

        cout << a.getMoney() << endl;

        a.setMoney(10);

        cout << a.getMoney() << endl;

        _setMoney(a, 20);

        cout << a.getMoney() << endl;
    }
```

After executing this in VS Code, I get `0, 10, 10` instead of `0, 10, 20`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are vectors passed to functions by value or by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647152/are-vectors-passed-to-functions-by-value-or-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `_setMoney()` being a `friend` or not.  If that were the issue, your code would not even compile.

The real issue is that you are passing the `a` object in `main()` *by value* to `_setmoney()`, so you are passing in a *copy* of the object, and are then modifying the *copy* rather than the *original* object.

Simply pass the object *by reference* instead:

```
void _setMoney(A& a, float i) {
    a.setMoney(i);
};
```

That being said, `A::setMoney()` is `public`, so `_setMoney()` does not need to be a `friend` of `A` in order to call it.  Only if `_setMoney()` wanted to access `A::money` directly, eg:

```
void _setMoney(A& a, float i) {
    a.setMoney(i); // <-- friend not required for this
    a.money = i; // <-- friend required for this
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    float money;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    friend void _setMoney(A& a, float i);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public:
    void setMoney(float i) {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        money = i;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    float getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    A(float i) {
        money = i;
    }

};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void _setMoney(A& a, float i) {
    a.money = i; // friend privilege
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(){
    A a(0);
    cout << a.getMoney() << endl;
    a.setMoney(10);
    cout << a.getMoney() << endl;
    _setMoney(a, 20);
    cout << a.getMoney() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add some explaination.